# remove lines when string has certain length with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing blocks of 4 lines that belong together. Structure looks like this

```
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@B1
ACDFS
+
B4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

Now when the length of the string of the second line of each block, is not equal to 9, I want the block of 4 to be removed. In this case, the 'B - block' would be removed. So my outputfile would look like this

```
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

I would use 'awk' to do this, but not sure how in this case.

Comment: @Laurel: no, this is random text actually. I will make some changes to the original post to better reflect the situation

Comment: How do you tell if it's a divider or a line?

Comment: @Laurel: Not sure that I understand what you mean, but there is an end-of-line character at the end of each line. So in this example here, the file contains 12 lines, the output file should contain 8 lines

Comment: By line I mean `A1`, `A2`, etc. By divider I mean the `ABCGKJTGE` stuff.

Comment: @Laurel: I've some edits. Every first line of the block start with '@', every third line of the block equals '+'

Comment: I always find it's easier to understand requirements written positively rather than negatively. Every command starts out with no output so to start your requirement by saying you want to remove something from it doesn't make sense. Instead of saying `I want to remove (negative) blocks containing 2nd lines that are not (negative) 9 characters long`, think of it as `I want to print blocks that containing 2nd lines that are 9 characters long`. No double negative and so much simpler to understand. Simply state what you want to output, not the change that creates compared to the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk cmd does the job:

```
 awk '{a[NR]=$0}
    END{for(i=2;i<=NR;i+=4)
            if(length(a[i])==9)
                p[i-1]=p[i]=p[i+1]=p[i+2]=1
        for(x=1;x<=NR;x++)
                if(p[x])print a[x]}' file
```

The idea is save all lines in an array, and check the interesting line, and decide if the "block" should be printed or not.

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
A1
NNNNNNNNN
A3
A4
B1
NNNNNNN
B3
B4
C1
NNNNNNNNN
C3
C4

kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$0}
        END{for(i=2;i<=NR;i+=4)
                        if(length(a[i])==9)
                                p[i-1]=p[i]=p[i+1]=p[i+2]=1
                for(x=1;x<=NR;x++)
                        if(p[x])print a[x]}' f
A1
NNNNNNNNN
A3
A4
C1
NNNNNNNNN
C3
C4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed -E 'N;N;N;/.*\n[^\n]{9}\n.*\n/ !d' test.txt
```

(Depending on your OS, `-E` may need to be `-r` instead.)

This should be read as "When you find a line, read three more lines (giving us four total), look for a second line that's exactly 9 characters long, and if **not** found, delete all four lines."

For a `test.txt` with this content:

```
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@B1
ACDFS
+
B4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

The output is:

```
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR%4 == 2 { lgth = length() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
NR%4 == 0 {
    if ( lgth == 9 ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another AWK solution, inspired by a previous solution:

```
$ cat > yetanother.awk
{
    a=a $0 ORS                       # thanks @Ed Morton
}
NR%4==0 {                            # for every 4th record
    split(a,b,ORS)                   # split gathered a to b
    if(length(b[2]==9))              # if the second record in block
        printf "%s", a                # print it
    a=""                             # reset a
}
```

And testing it:

```
$ awk -f yetanother.awk structure.txt
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
        arr[NR%4]=$0
        #dbg print "dbg: NR%4=" NR%4 "\tarr[2]="arr[2]"\tlen="length(arr[2])
        if (NR%4==0 && (length(arr[2]) == 9)) {
                print arr[1]"\n"arr[2]"\n"arr[3]"\n"arr[0]
        }
} ' data
```

**output**

```
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
```

The one tricky part here is that `arr[NR%4]` references `arr[0]`. So we have to change from the "logical" `arr[4]` to `arr[0]` in the `print` statement.

If you have more than 4 lines per "record" you can parameterize that value, and then use it to drive a `for` loop to print the saved record, i.e.

```
 for (i=1; i<=recSize; i++) {
   print arr[i]
 }
 print arr[0]
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk multiline records

```
awk '
BEGIN{ RS="(^|\n)@[^\n]*\n" }
length($1) == 9 {printf("%s%s", prt, $0)}
{prt=RT}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org.txr):

```
@(repeat)
@@@head
@{line2 9}
@line3
@line4
@  (output)
@@@head
@line2
@line3
@line4
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data
@A1
ABCGKJTGE
+
A4
@C1
SFDGDGDAD
+
C4
```